# Upper Bound on Vector Length

Tags: geometry, vectors

I read the following statement in [a solution set](http://vision.caltech.edu/~kchalupk/spivak.html) for the famous *"Calculus on Manifolds"* by Spivak (see **2-12** in the linked page):

> Note that for any vector $a=(a^1,a^2,\cdots, a^n)$ we  have $|a|\leq|(a^{i_1},a^{i_2},\cdots,a^{i_k})|$ for any choice of $i$.

I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. I originally thought this meant that any combination of, even possibly repeating, indices $i_j$ (for any $j$ between $1$ and $k$), the above inequality will hold. That's not true at all though, so it must mean something else that I'm not getting.

Comment: I think they mean without repeats.  In particular, I think they mean any selection of $i_j$ where
$$
i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k
$$

Comment: Can you provide a link for where you read this?

Comment: http://vision.caltech.edu/~kchalupk/spivak.html Look at **2-12**.

Comment: I've edited the question to show where I found the statement.